# Separated Textboxes Put Back Into One Variable And Displayed Differently

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, variables

Hello very smart people of the internet. I have a question that I can't seem to get right. I have three textboxes in a form, which represent 3 different parts of a phone number. Here is the code for them.

```
            <form name="addacell" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" name="phoneNumber" id="addcell1"/ size="1" placeholder="XXX">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" name="phoneNumber" id="addcell2" size="1"/ placeholder="XXX">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="phoneNumber" id="addcell3" size="2" placeholder="XXXX"/>
```

Next, I am submitting the form and running some validation to check if it meets the phone requirements I have set up for it. (Ignore validation I am not dealing with it until I get everything else straightened out)

```
<input type="submit" name="submitcell" value="Add" id="submitcell" class="sm-button" onclick="return validatePhone(document.addacell.addcell);"/>
```

Here is what I need help with: I need to put these 3 individual parts of the phone number together, store it as XXXXXXXXXX in a variable, display it as (XXX)XXX-XXXX and then award you with a huge internet hug.

Thanks in advance for all your hard work for me!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: I've tried adding the strings together but nothing turns out correctly, so I came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: don't name all the separate parts of the phone number the same thing.
Try phone1, phone2 and phone3 in the `name` attribute of each `input`.

In your PHP code, something simple as:

```
$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
$phone3 = $_POST['phone3'];

// store
$store = $phone1.$phone2.$phone3; // do whatever you want with this

// display
$display = "(".$phone1.")".$phone2."-".$phone3;
```

Also, there seems to be some misplaced "/" in your code. Check that.

Comment: No prob, that's why we're here. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, rename your inputs. They're all called 'phoneNumber'.
Then call something like `$sPhoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber1'] . '-' . $_POST['phoneNumber2'] . '-' . $_POST['phoneNumber3'];`

The variable `$sPhoneNumber` now contains the input from the 3 fields (renamed to phoneNumber1, phoneNumber 2 and phoneNumber3).

Answer (score 0):

Using some basic Javascript you can build the strings you are looking for.

```
var text1 = document.getElementById(addcell1).value;
var text2 = document.getElementById(addcell2).value;
var text3 = document.getElementById(addcell3).value;

var storeText = text1 + text2 + text3;
var displayText = "(" + text1 + ")" + text2 + "-" + text3;
```